# Fit table into div without scroll

Tags: html, scrollbar

I am trying to fit a table (**tblCharts**) into another div (**graphsDiv**) and to remove vertical scroll. My current code is

```
<div class="row" style="padding-top:0px; margin-top:0px;  margin-right:0px; border:groove; height:610px; overflow:auto" id="graphsDiv">

 </div>
```

**On Page Load**

```
$(function(){
   var tableHTML = '<table id="tblCharts" style="width:100%; height: 100%; ">';
   for (var j = 0; j < rows; j++) {

        tableHTML += '<tr>';

        for (var k = 0; k < cols; k++) {
            tableHTML += '<td id="td style="border:none;"><div id="chart' + j + k + '"  ></div></td>';
        }
        tableHTML += '</tr>';
   }
   tableHTML += '</table>';

   $('#graphsDiv').append(tableHTML);
});
```

inside each chartjk div there is a chart loaded afterwards. Current screen shot is attached.[image]

If i change graphsDiv height, to 100% it overflows its own container..

```
<div id="graphsWindow">
    <div class="table">
        <div class="row" style="margin-left:0px;margin-top:0px; padding-top:0px; padding-bottom:0px">
        <div style="border:groove; margin-left:10px; margin-bottom:0px; padding-bottom:0px; margin-right:2px" class="col-md-2">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9" style="padding-bottom:0px; padding-top:0px; margin-top:0px; margin-left:15px;">
            <div class="row" style="padding-top:0px; margin-top:0px;  margin-right:0px; border:groove; height:610px; overflow:auto" id="graphsDiv">

            </div>        
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: have you tried overflow-x: hidden; ?

Comment: on which item? graphsDiv or tblCharts?

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem here

```
'<td id="td style="border:none;"><div id="chart'
```

The id doesn't have a closed ", so that's worth fixing.
Also could you share the whole page, say in a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/).
In general if you want to stop scrolling from happening use overflow-y: hidden. That said I think a better solution could be figured out if I can see the whole page.

Comment: Oh I didn't mean that ahah. Like where is rows defined? Could you possibly upload the whole project folder to google drive and link me? Or if it's on github you could link me to that :)

Comment: rows and cols are equal to any number e.g. 2 rows and 4 cols. Sorry cant upload the project

Comment: Sorry, but I can't help if I don't know what's going on.